# MacOSX 10.7 ROS Installation python-eggs write permission error

Tags: ros, macos, homebrew, macos-lion, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Following Homebrew instructions on http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/OSX/Homebrew, Desktop-Full rosinstall, stops with this error message:
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 928, in extraction_error
raise err
pkg_resources.ExtractionError: Can't extract file(s) to egg cache

The following error occurred while trying to extract file(s) to the Python egg
cache:

[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/Ross/.python-eggs/PyYAML-3.10-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg-tmp/tmpjfwmGh.$extract'

The Python egg cache directory is currently set to:

/Users/Ross/.python-eggs

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  You can
change the cache directory by setting the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE environment
variable to point to an accessible directory.

How to I set write authority to this directory or other action to allow this file to be written?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31858/macosx-10.7-ros-installation-python-eggs-write-permission-error/) by [RobotRoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/1992/robotross/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2012-04-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

"How to I set write authority to this directory or other action to allow this file to be written?"

to modify permissions:

```
sudo chown -R $USER {directory/file}
sudo chmod -R u+rwx {directory/file}
```

chown changes owner to you the user and chmod adds read/write/and execute&search to you. Please **replace** {directory/file} with either a directory name (and the -R will recursively change everything within) or a file name. To learn more about these commands, type:

```
man chown
```

or

```
man chmod
```

in a terminal window and read the man pages.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1